# Why this Tap function script is not working?

Tags: javascript

I want to put tap function in other content too but it is not working.

when you click tap on the top, each tap display proper content.

in there i want to put more content, so i made #Hometwo, #Newstwo, #Contacttwo, #Abouttwo

so when i clicked Home tap then it show #Home and #Hometwo text.

but it only works on #Home.
why is it not working on "#Hometwo"?

what should i do to make it work on "#Hometwo" either??

any help will be so appreciated. thanks!

```js
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");

  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";

}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Style tab links */
.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
.tabcontent {
  color: black;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'Hometwo')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'Newstwo')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'Contacttwo')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'Abouttwo')">About</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="Home" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Home</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="News" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>News</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Contact</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="About" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>About</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>this is text which always have to be displayed</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td id="Hometwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Home2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Newstwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>News2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Contacttwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Contact2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Abouttwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>About2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your `openPage` function accepts three params, the third being the color:

```
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
```

But you're passing `'Hometwo'` for your third params on the clickevent. So either change that, or add a string to the display in your `openPage` function.

Here's a working sample:

```js
    function openPage(pageName,elmnt,pageName2) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "";
  document.getElementById(pageName2).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = "";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}

/* Set height of body and the document to 100% */
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Style tab links */
.tablink {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 25%;
}

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

/* Style the tab content (and add height:100% for full page content) */
.tabcontent {
  color: black;
  display: none;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home', this, 'Hometwo')">Home</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('News', this, 'Newstwo')" id="defaultOpen">News</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact', this, 'Contacttwo')">Contact</button>
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About', this, 'Abouttwo')">About</button>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="Home" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Home</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="News" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>News</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Contact</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="About" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>About</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td>this is text which always have to be displayed</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td id="Hometwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Home2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Newstwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>News2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Contacttwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>Contact2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="Abouttwo" class="tabcontent">
            <div>
              <h3>About2</h3>
              <p>Home is where the heart is..</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Hi @Prosy Arceno! Thanks a lot!!! it is exactly what i want!! really thanks and have a great day!!! :D thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. This happens to the best of us, don't worry.